# How to make changes to a python executable file without compiling a new one?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to be able to run python scripts in the background of my computer, with no terminal while being to edit it whenever.
I can already create executable files, with no terminal, with pyinstaller but at the cost of having to create a new compiled version every time I make changes.

Basically all I am asking is if there is any method of where I can just make changes in i.e Visual Studio and then rerun the executable?

Comment: If you're talking about running Python code on your own computer, then why are you producing executables at all?  Just run the scripts themselves.  The only point of executable files is to be able to run on other computers that don't have Python installed.

Comment: @jasonharper jeez, should of thought of that, thanks and sorry for the silly question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can run Python without a console by changing the extension of the Python file to `.pyw`. The `.pyw` extension tells Python to run the script without opening a console window.